# How can I convert a String of hex value array to ByteArray and vice versa in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I have a string of hex value array:

`val intArr = "[61, 62, 63]"` // correspond to "abc"

I want to convert it to `ByteArray`(of array of these 3 hex values) and convert that `ByteArray` back to the original string (not "abc" but to "[61, 62, 63]")?

Comment: question updated

Comment: Note that absolutely nothing you've mentioned in your question actually has anything to do with hex.

Answer (score 0):

got it figured out by trimming the array symbol and converting all hexes to decimal numbers then:

```
val list: List<String> = str.split(",").toList()
val bytes: ByteArray = ByteArray(list.size){
     list[it].toByte()
}
```